# Help with understanding Symmetric and anti-symmetric problems in an equation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So I know how to prove that they are not symmetric or not anti symmetric but in case of proving they are, I get a little confused on it. For example:

$2x^2-3xy + y^2 = 0$ can be written as $2x^2-xy-2xy+y^2=0$ then $x(2x-y)+y(2x-y)=0$
$(2x-y)(x+y)=0$ so $2x=y$ or $x=y$ but now I stop since I know it is anti-symmetric because it can not be symmetric since if try $1R2$ it work but not $2R1$ and i know $x=y$ so it must be anti symmetric but I do not know how to write it in an exam.

(same problem with symmetric I but lack an equation that got the same process as this that I know will be symmetric)

So what I'm facing here to be exact is that i got these answers like $x=y$ and $x=2y$ how do I use them to prove what I want to be true.

I know the generic formula for solving symmetric and anti symmetric but in this type of equation when it comes to "for all $x$" I start asking myself "is this enough?" "was it proven yet?".

Hope my question was clear.

Answer (score 1):

The correct terminology for your example is non-symmetric, or just "not symmetric". Or "not symmetric in $x,y$". Because if it were symmetric in $x,y$ it would mean that it is equivalent to the sentence resulting from changing every occurrence of $x$ with $y$, and vice-versa.

You have $2x^2-3xy+y^2=0\iff (2x-y)(x+y)=0 \iff (y=2x \lor y=-x)$....

... not $(y=2x \lor y=x)$.

Comment: Ohhhh that's on me it was late and kind of messed that up but that means that we don't get x=y how do we prove it as anti-symmetric?. Also I'll fix that error thanks